# Workflow list association missing after site import

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

After importing a site to a new site collection, every workflow now is missing its list association. Is this typical in a site move? Also, how can I add this back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical, since all of the GUIDs change. In the future, look into using reusable workflows. To re-associate your lists, you'll have to update the xml files directly. [This article](https://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/howto-move-or-migrate-sharepoint-2010-list-based-workflows-between-sites-and-site-collections/) will step you through getting the new GUIDs and updating the XML files.

Comment: This method on worked for 2010 workflows. Maybe there is a powershell solution.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 2013 on-premise

Comment: Have you tried removing the workflows, then packaging and deploying them from template? [Package and Deploy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/30/packaging-list-site-and-reusable-workflow-and-how-to-deploy-the-package.aspx); [moving workflows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/18/how-to-use-the-visual-designer-to-move-workflows-between-sites.aspx); [Moving workflows w/ visual designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/18/how-to-use-the-visual-designer-to-move-workflows-between-sites.aspx)

Comment: Yea, I've tried that. It exports to a blank single step diagram.